# Is it possible to declare a general reference to any struct in Julia?

Tags: templates, struct, types, reference, julia

I want to known if it is possible to implement a general reference inside a struct.
The code is :

```
struct Foo1
  ia :: Int
end


struct Foo2{UNKNOWNTYPE}
  ref :: UNKNOWNTYPE
  ib :: Int
  
  function Foo2{UNKNOWNTYPE}(ref::UNKNOWNTYPE,ib::Int)
    o = new{UNKNOWNTYPE}(ref,ib) 
    return o
  end
end

foo1 = Foo1();
foo2 = Foo2{Foo1}(foo1,1)
```

In the above code, the type of variable `ref` in struct Foo2 is undetermined until running time. The above code does not work and it shows : "LoadError("main.jl", 6, UndefVarError(:UNKNOWNTYPE))".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're basically just missing a `where UNKNOWNTYPE` in your constructor definition. I'd recommend using a outer constructor for `Foo2` like so

```
julia> struct Foo1
         ia::Int
       end

julia> struct Foo2{T}
         ref::T
         ib::Int
       end

julia> Foo2(ref::T, ib::Int) where T = Foo2{T}(ref, ib)
Foo2

julia> Foo2(Foo1(1), 1)
Foo2{Foo1}(Foo1(1), 1)
```

but an inner constructor works too:

```
julia> struct Foo3{T}
         ref::T
         ib::Int

         function Foo3(ref::T, ib::Int) where T
           return new{T}(ref, ib)
         end
       end

julia> Foo3(Foo1(1), 2)
Foo3{Foo1}(Foo1(1), 2)
```

Comment: What is the benefit of using an outer constructor?

Comment: It doesn't remove the default inner constructor, so you can still do something like `Foo2{Float64}(1,2)`.